# Power BI Service Analysis Services database connection string

Tags: excel-2013, powerbi, powerquery, ssas-2012

The Power BI Service "Analyse in Excel" feature produces an `.odc` file that is exported, downloaded onto local machine, and when executed which opens Excel, creates Excel cube and Pivot Table using the Power BI data.

I have been trying to use the `.odc`connection file information to put together a url that I can use in Power Query to connect to the Power BI Analysis Services database that hosts the report's data source.

This is connection string from `.odc`  file:

```
<odc:ConnectionString>
Provider=MSOLAP.7;
Integrated Security=ClaimsToken;
Data Source=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api;
;
Initial Catalog=37c4ee9e-6cf5-49d2-aaa7-e66e42646274;
Location=https://wabi-west-us-redirect.analysis.windows.net/xmla?vs=sobe_wowvirtualserver&db=37c4ee9e-6cf5-49d2-aaa7-e66e42646274;
MDX Compatibility= 1; 
MDX Missing Member Mode= Error; 
Safety Options= 2; 
Update Isolation Level= 2
</odc:ConnectionString>
```

The `.odc` file also contains an url in the  though this ends up in the `Name` field of the Excel Data Connection:

```
<title>https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api; 37c4619e-6cf5-49d2-aaa7-e66e42646274 Model
</title>
```

I am guessing that this is the AS database url from the .odc file:

```
https://wabi-west-us-redirect.analysis.windows.net/xmla?vs=sobe_wowvirtualserver&db=37c4ee9e-6cf5-49d2-aaa7-e66e42646274
```

So using that AS url I create Power Query SSAS connector like this:

```
= AnalysisServices.Databases("https://wabi-west-us-redirect.analysis.windows.net/xmla?vs=sobe_wowvirtualserver&db=37c4ee9e-6cf5-49d2-aaa7-e66e42646274")
```

I enter my Power BI Service username and password as `Basic` authentication with `Private` security status.

The Power Query Loads without error, runs for brief second, then shows error:

```
DataSource.Error: AnalysisServices: The connection either timed out or was lost.
```

Has anyone else done this? Is there more the AS database url than I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it these use 2 different architectures: ADOMD vs XMLA, so I don't think this will work. The first parameter of AnalysisServices.Databases is servername, not a URI for XMLA.